# Resizing NSView / NSOpenGLView on window resize

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I currently have a mac application with the window size on opening set at 480 x 560, within this window there is an `NSOpenGLView`, in the reshape function for this I have the following:

```
NSLog(@"Reshaping");
float screenWidth = (float)[_window frame].size.width;
float screenHeight = (float)[_window frame].size.height;
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-10, 110, -10, 110, -1, 1);
```

This all seems to work fine from the OpenGL side with the image stretching etc but when I make the window larger than it originally was the OpenGL view doesn't seem to want to change (however the OpenGL within it does). I printed the following values out to see what was wrong:

```
NSLog(@"width 1:",[_window frame].size.width);
NSLog(@"width 2:",[self bounds].size.width);
NSLog(@"width 3:",[[self superview] bounds].size.width);
```

And the only one which changes is the first one, can the other two be updated manually (I tried setting them to the window frame values but these are read only..) or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it in the end, i just typed the following into the `NSOpenGLView` class.

```
[[self superview]setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
```

It can take any of the values listed [Here on the NSView Class Reference Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Resizing_masks)

They can also be combined as using the OR operator as below:

```
[[self superview]setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
```

As I'm not using a XIB file, this takes the place of the diagram in Interface Builder which changed how the view changed size when the window changed size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 5, you may want to use the [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html) in interface builder. In particular, select your NSOpenGLView, click the "Pin" constraints button in the lower right corner of the canvas, then click all four dashed red brackets to make them solid red. This will constrain the NSOpenGLView to its superview's dimensions.

[image: Constraints]

Comment: You can only use this method if you're using a nib file; I wasn't for this project!